# Can someone help me on how to handle CORS to access other site collection in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

Scenario:
I have one Site Collection in abc.com domain and other Site Collection I have inside xyz.com domain. Now I want to access list item from abc.com domain inside xyz.com domain. Both Sites are created in Office 365. I tried with JSOM and REST api but it fails while making call.

Please advice with code sample.

Thanks!

Comment: Call to another domain not working, try JQuery JSONP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409155/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-to-another-domain

Comment: I already tried with JSONP but it didn't work for me. And how we would authenticate users through code from other domain. Pls share code sample if any...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the two site collection in a same tenant and use have permission to get list data from another site collection.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var siteCollUrl="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
    var listName="CustomList";
    $.ajax({
        url: siteCollUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var titles="";
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                titles+="Title:"+item.Title+"\n";
            });
            alert(titles);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
})
</script>
```